# Correct current state after each run

Tags: javascript

I am having an array that is having a *product*, an *url* and a *state*.

I would like to run it through a while-loop and with each run get only the objects that have a `state = true`.

Currently I run in an endless loop:

```js
const product = ['Product 1', 'Product 2']

const res = []
for (let i = 0; i < product.length; i++) {
  res.push({
    product: product[i],
    url: 'price',
    state: false,
  }, {
    product: product[i],
    url: 'groceries/',
    state: false,
  }, {
    product: product[i],
    url: 'car',
    state: false,
  }, {
    product: product[i],
    url: 'automotive/',
    state: false,
  }, {
    product: product[i],
    url: 'computer/',
    state: false,
  })
}

function setState(res, state) {
  res.state = state
}

function getState(res) {
  return res.state
}

let currentState = res.filter(el => el.state = true)
let i = 0
while (currentState.length > 0) {
  currentState = res.filter(el => el.state = true)
  this.setState(res[i], false)
  console.log(`Set state to false for ${JSON.stringify(res[i])}`)
  console.log(currentState.length)
  i++
}
```

Any suggestions how to get only the objects where the `state = true` and set the state after each run to true so that my loop terminates?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: `res.filter(el => el.state = true)` that is incorrect, `=` is for assignment, use `==` or `===` for comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues here your using = instead of == and your rechecking for states too early

It should also be noted that you really dont need == true it can just be res.filter(el => el.state)

```
let currentState = res.filter(el => el.state == true)
let i = 0
while (currentState.length > 0) {
  this.setState(res[i], false)
  currentState = res.filter(el => el.state == true)
  console.log(`Set state to false for ${JSON.stringify(res[i])}`)
  console.log(currentState.length)
  i++
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are setting all the elements' state to true by using `=` (the assignment operator) instead of `==` or `===` which are comparison operators.

In your particular situation, it doesn't look like you need either one, because el.state is a boolean anyway, so you can just do `res.filter(el => el.state)`

Answer (score 1):

You are doing

array.filter(e1=> e1.state = true)

e1.state = true assigns e1.state value to true and returns the value that is assigned.

Filter return those elements which returns true.

Since every elements state is being assigned true and always true is returned, it returns the same array instead of filtering it.

Use

array.filter(e1=> e1.state ==  true)